# What is the latest Java JRE1.8 that you can install out-of-box on WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, java, jre

In the past `Java JRE 1.8`  could not be installed on WinXp. The error message was:

> the procedure entry point RegDeleteKeyExA could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error/21202600#21202600) in an answer **Oracle has announced fix for Windows XP installation error** that Oracle fixed that bug in JRE8u25. Quote:

> I'm adding this answer since Oracle has decided to fix Windows XP
>   installation. As of the JRE 8u25 release in 10/15/2014 the bug has
>   been fixed that prevented Windows XP installation.
>
> However, this does not mean that Oracle is continuing to support
>   Windows XP. They make no guarantee about current and future releases
>   of JRE8 being compatible with Windows XP. It looks like it's a run at
>   your own risk kind of thing.

I know this is a bad idea, but I need it only for testing. So my question is: what is the latest update of JRE1.8 version that support out-of-box installation on WinXP (between JRE8u25 and todays JRE8u172? I tried 8u25 and it works. However 8u172 doesn't install.

I could try to dowload it with a 'binary search', but maybe someone has this information?

Comment: It sounds like the answer to your question is JRE8u25.  It sounds like Oracle simply fixed the installation executable to support the operating systems they claimed it supported.  Of course they fixed it back in 2014.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I tried 8u161 and it failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JDK 8u152 will install out-of-the box, and I have it working on my XP 32-bit laptop.  I have not been able to install u162 or u161 successfully thus far.

It's worth noting that some of the later updates break compatibility with parts of JavaFX.  Starting with u112, the JavaFX WebView does not work on XP (it works on u111), and starting with u151, nearly any JavaFX action will crash the VM.  Thus I recommend an update in the u60 to u111 range if you are using JavaFX (u60 added additional JavaFX controls).  These issues affect both XP 32-bit and XP Pro x64.

I have not found any other bugs with Java 8 on XP over the past 4 years, but there are areas of the JDK that I don't use.

Answer (score 1):

Heavily changed new version of my answer:

**NetBeans 8.2** seems to work fine with **Java8 SDK update 51** on

**Windows XP Home Edition Version 2002 Service Pack 3**. JDK includes JRE. As of 2023_07_12 I downloaded the

```
jdk-8u51-windows-i586.exe
```

from

https://archive.org/details/Java_8_update_51

Thank You for reading my comment and thank You for the answers :-)

Comment: to clarify - does it fail on SP3, would it work, or is it untested?

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to specify what SP version it does work on and leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s) to everybody. Being influenced by Your comment(s), I just did that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe the JRE8u172 suffers from the installer compatibility problem?  More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error/21202600#21202600

As for JRE 8, the last I have seen installed is JRE8u161.

Comment: I have that link up, too. Ok, you have reduced my choice. I will try 8u161.